# googlemap markers loading in the middle of the map

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I developed an ios application that uses googlemaps, and involves markers on this map.

I got an issue reported from two iphone users(iphone6, iphone5s) that all the markers are appearing in the middle of the sea(probably at coordinates '0,0').

I have retested the application on all iphone versions and no issues of this sort have appeared.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Check whether, Location permission is given to your application or not.

Comment: Check Settings > Privacy > Location Services . It must be ON.

Comment: changing location services value doesnt do any difference. the coordinates are received from a server along with other data, and not from the user's location.

Comment: Would it be the network connection?

Comment: All the data for the markers is confirmed to have been received from the contents of the infowindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It a locale issue. If your user's device has "," as a decimal separator - Google Maps considers coordinate invalid and uses 0 instead.

Comment: Thanks alot this was the problem, users having this issue had their region selected to France, which uses decimal seperators as a ',' instead of a '.'

Answer (score 0):

So correct me if I have misunderstood it. You are fetching the coordinates (Latitudes and Longitude) from server along with some content and want to display that on the Google Maps. And as soon as you open your app the markers instead of appearing on the specified coordinates are appearing in the center of the map.

In this case it looks like you are not using the camera position. With camera position you can specify the following properties:

- [Latitude/Longitude](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#location)
- [Zoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#zoom)
- [Bearing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#bearing_orientation)
- [Viewing Angle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views#viewing_angle)

Here is the code for objective C

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                                        longitude:151.2086
                                                             zoom:16];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
```

And for Swift:

```
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.8683,
    longitude: 151.2086, zoom: 16)
var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
```

Dont keep if default else it would locate the markers at the center.

Hope that Helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your app isn't handling bad / no data connection properly.  The server can't be reached and the app throws a zero, zero lat lng.